# Create Sqlite database patches while updating

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x, diff, patch, python-db-api

**Context:**
A python 3.6 script is updating a Sqlite database several times a day using [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html) module.
The database is ~500Mo, each update adds up ~250Ko.

**Issue:**
I deliver every updated versions of the database and would like to reduce the size of the data transferred. In other words, I would like to transfer only the updated content (through a kind of patch).
The [sqldiff.exe](https://www.sqlite.org/sqldiff.html) utility program could be used for that, nevertheless, it requires to create a local copy of the database every time I update it.

**Question:**
**Is there a way, using Python (through the [DB-API 2.0 interface](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) or using other ways in Python), to generate this kind of patch while updating the database?**

---

*First thoughts:*
Wouldn't it be possible to write a patch (*e.g.* a list of actions to be done to update the database) based on the cursor before/while performing the commit?

```
import sqlite3

# Open database
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Insert/Update data
new_data = 3.14
cur.execute('INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?)', (new_data,))

# KEEP TRACK & Save (commit) the changes 
conn.dump_planned_actions()  # ?????
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: The [session extension](http://www.sqlite.org/sessionintro.html) is not enabled in Python.

Comment: @CL. would you know workarounds? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet shows the workaround I found.

It relies on the Sqlite3 method `set_trace_callback` to log all the SQL statements sent and `executescript` to apply these statements.

```
import sqlite3

class DBTraceCallbackHandler(object):
    """Class handling callbacks in order to log sql statements history."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.sql_statements = []
    def instance_handler(self, event):
        self.sql_statements.append(str(event))

def database_modification(cursor):
    # user-defined
    pass

def create_patch(db_path):
    # Openning connection
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    c = conn.cursor()
    # Start tracing sql
    callback_handler = DBTraceCallbackHandler()
    conn.set_trace_callback(callback_handler.instance_handler)
    # Modification of database
    database_modification(c)
    # End of modification of database
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    # Generating the patch - selecting sql statements that modify the db
    idx_rm = []
    for idx, sql_statement in enumerate(callback_handler.sql_statements):
        if not any([sql_statement.startswith(kw) for kw in ['UPDATE', 'INSERT', 'CREATE']]):
            idx_rm.append(idx)
    for idx in sorted(idx_rm, reverse=True):
        del callback_handler.sql_statements[idx]

    return ';\n'.join(callback_handler.sql_statements) + ';\n'


def apply_patch(db_path, sql_script):
    # Openning connection
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    c = conn.cursor()
    # Modification of database - apply sql script
    c.executescript(sql_script)
    # End of modification of database
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
```